# WEBRTC: How to deal with conflicts?

Tags: javascript, webrtc

I am posting this question because I currently have some issues with WEBRTC in Javascript.

First of all, my implementation works pretty well and I can communicate with one or more people at the same time.

However, the context, where i use webrtc, can sometimes lead to a client creating multiple offers in a few ms (using STUN server) and sending those offers to multiple other client.

The issue is: sometimes the client connects really well to one or more other clients but the connection fails with the rest of clients he sent the offers. (and it is not an issue with particular client because all clients can connect each other if they send offers in a longer timing)

I suppose it is a conflict between sdp offers (maybe port conflict ?) that are generated by a same client in a too short time before the end of connection's establishments.

My question is how can i deal with it ? Is it possible to detect when connection fails and then create a new offer ? Should I check the sdp messages in my signal server to ask a client to create a new offer when he sends 2 offers that are conflicting ?

Thanks for your answers.

P.S:
Sorry for my bad language, I am not native english speaker. :/

Comment: perhaps it is much better if you include some of your js code